# I would like to remove date display on photo preview

Tags: plugins, posts, css

I have a web site and in the image preview of the posts, when I display images, there is a date displayed by the website and I would like to remove it. I've looked in the wordpress config but I haven't found anything so I think I have to take a look at the code but I'm new in wordpress and I don't know what file I have to edit to remove that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
here a capture of what I'm trying to remove:

[image]

Edit to add css file:

```
    /*
Theme Name: Peliegro
Theme URI: http://themeforest.net/user/Peenapo/portfolio?ref=Peenapo
Author: Peenapo
Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/Peenapo
Description: Theme by Peenapo Themes
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
Text Domain: peliegro
Domain Path: /lang/

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

Bad Weather Framework is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2014 Automattic, Inc.

Resetting and rebuilding styles have been helped along thanks to the fine work of
Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
along with Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/
and Blueprint http://www.blueprintcss.org/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
>>> TABLE OF CONTENTS:
----------------------------------------------------------------
1.0 - Reset
2.0 - Typography
3.0 - Elements
4.0 - Forms
5.0 - Navigation
    5.1 - Links
    5.2 - Menus
6.0 - Accessibility
7.0 - Alignments
8.0 - Clearings
9.0 - Widgets
10.0 - Content
    10.1 - Posts and pages
    10.2 - Asides
    10.3 - Comments
11.0 - Infinite scroll
12.0 - Media
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
1.0 - Reset
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* Corrects text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units http://clagnut.com/blog/348/#c790 */
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/ /* Keeps page centered in all browsers regardless of content height */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom */
    -ms-text-size-adjust:     100%; /* www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/ */
}
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements; see http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Not needed for modern webkit but still used by Blackberry Browser 7.0; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; /* Still needed for Firefox 28; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table { /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
    outline: 0;
}
a img {
    border: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
2.0 Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
dfn, cite, em, i {
    font-style: italic;
}
blockquote {
    margin: 0 1.5em;
}
address {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
pre {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1.6em;
}
code, kbd, tt, var {
    font: 15px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
}
abbr, acronym {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    cursor: help;
}
mark, ins {
    background: #fff9c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
sup,
sub {
    font-size: 75%;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
    bottom: 1ex;
}
sub {
    top: .5ex;
}
small {
    font-size: 75%;
}
big {
    font-size: 125%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
3.0 Elements
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
hr {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;
}
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}
li > ul,
li > ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
}
table {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}
th {
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
4.0 Forms
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* Corrects font size not being inherited in all browsers */
    margin: 0; /* Addresses margins set differently in IE6/7, F3/4, S5, Chrome */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* Improves appearance and consistency in IE6/IE7 */
}
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer; /* Improves usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type 'input' and others */
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* Corrects inability to style clickable 'input' types in iOS */
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border:0;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
button:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
button:active,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {

}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    padding: 0; /* Addresses excess padding in IE8/9 */
}
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* Addresses appearance set to searchfield in S5, Chrome */
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration { /* Corrects inner padding displayed oddly in S5, Chrome on OSX */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { /* Corrects inner padding and border displayed oddly in FF3/4 www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/14/the-devils-in-the-details-fixing-dojos-toolbar-buttons/ */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
textarea {
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    color: #111;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
    padding: 7px;
}
textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE6/7/8/9 */
    padding-left: 3px;
    vertical-align: top; /* Improves readability and alignment in all browsers */
    width: 98%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.0 Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.1 Links
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
a {
    color: royalblue;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: midnightblue;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.2 Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item a {
}
/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-toggle,
    .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
    }


}
.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .paging-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.paging-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.paging-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
6.0 Accessibility
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute !important;
}

.screen-reader-text:hover,
.screen-reader-text:active,
.screen-reader-text:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    clip: auto !important;
    color: #21759b;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 15px 23px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 5px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar */
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
7.0 Alignments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
8.0 Clearings
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:before,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.clear:after,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
9.0 Widgets
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.widget {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* Make sure select elements fit in widgets */
.widget select {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Search widget */
.widget_search .search-submit {
    display: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.0 Content
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.1 Posts and pages
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.sticky {
}
.hentry {
    margin:0;
}
.byline,
.updated {
    display: none;
}
.single .byline,
.group-blog .byline {
    display: inline;
}
.page-content,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin: 0;
}
.page-links {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.2 Asides
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.blog .format-aside .entry-title,
.archive .format-aside .entry-title {
    display: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.3 Comments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.comment-content a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.bypostauthor {
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
11.0 Infinite scroll
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Globally hidden elements when Infinite Scroll is supported and in use. */
.infinite-scroll .paging-navigation, /* Older / Newer Posts Navigation (always hidden) */
.infinite-scroll.neverending .site-footer { /* Theme Footer (when set to scrolling) */
    display: none;
}
/* When Infinite Scroll has reached its end we need to re-display elements that were hidden (via .neverending) before */
.infinity-end.neverending .site-footer {
    display: block;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
12.0 Media
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.page-content img.wp-smiley,
.entry-content img.wp-smiley,
.comment-content img.wp-smiley {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wp-caption {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.wp-caption img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.2% auto 0;
    max-width: 98%;
}
.wp-caption-text {
    text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    margin: 0.8075em 0;
}
.site-main .gallery {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.gallery-caption {
}
.site-main .gallery a img {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}
.site-main .gallery dd,
.site-main .gallery figcaption {
    margin: 0;
}
.site-main .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
}
.site-main .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item img {
}

/* Make sure embeds and iframes fit their containers */
embed,
iframe,
object {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* add theme options icon - admin bar (front) */
.bw-admin-bar-options a:before {content:'\f100';top:2px;}
```

Comment: What is the page URL?

Comment: www.guiasdelsur.com

Comment: I can't see anything like the screenshot in your URL.

Comment: excuse me is guiasdelsur.es, not .com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions: CSS edit and File edit.

CSS edit(Not the best solution, but works)

```
.post-blocks .block-info span { display: none; }
```

It is not possible for us to write the file edit code since we don't have access to your admin panel.

Install `WhatTheFile` plugin to find out the template that renders the code for the page and edit the `<span>` element inside .block-info. Make sure you are using `Child theme` before editing via both methods.

Comment: Sorry I've try to edit css file but haven't been able to find were to put this line of code you provided me. Could you tell me please were do I have to put it??

Comment: Post the CSS code in the style.css of the child theme folder. You can use this plugin to create the child theme: https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

Comment: I've followed your instructions and everything works just fine, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I have a last question. How can I remove the date displayed under the title here http://guiasdelsur.es/aventura-2/

Comment: Add `.post-heading .sub-info .sub-content > span { display: none; }` but I would say this is not the best way. File editing is that standard way. This is good for temporary purpose.